# how to hide a div of ngFor and show according to previous ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular8

I want to get the month line, of the specific year i click, so that i will be able to link it to the further datasets.

```
<div class="list-float-right">
    <ul >                  
      <li *ngFor="let years of yearData">
        <a href=#{{years.year}}>{{years.year}}</a> 
          </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="list-float-right">
    <ul>                  
      <div *ngFor="let years of yearData">
        <li *ngFor="let months of years.monthData">

            {{months.month}}


        </li>
              <br>
     </div>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div *ngFor="let years of yearData">
    <div id={{years.year}}>
      {{years.year}}
      <br>
          The color of animals <br>is by no means <br>a matter of chance;
           <br>it depends on many considerations, 
           <br>but in the majority of cases tends to protect the animal 
           from danger by rendering it less conspicuous. 
       <hr>
      </div>
```

```
yearData = [{
    year:2019,
    monthData: [
      { month : "jan"},
      { month : "july"}
    ]
  },{
    year:2018,
    monthData: [
      { month : "march"},
      { month : "april"}
    ]
  },{
    year:2017,
    monthData: [
      { month : "march"},
      { month : "dec"}
    ]
  },{
    year:2016,
    monthData: [
      { month : "march"},
      { month : "feb"}
    ]
  },{
    year:2015,
    monthData: [
      { month : "jan"},
      { month : "may"}
    ]
  }
];
```

Data are linked over each year and in each month. so if i click a year as 2019 and then options come of the year which are available in the given year.

**output format**

year bar
month bar as available to the given year .

also if no year is selected ,it would automatically point to the latest year month. like in the given json it should give the months of year-2019.

**expected output**

2019 2018 2017 2016 2015 // if i click 2018 it will show in the next line

march april // & if i have not clicked any year , it will give of 2019.

Comment: Have you tried the  solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

Template:

```
<div class="list-float-right">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let years of yearData">
            <a href=#{{years.year}} (click)="selectedYear =years.year">{{years.year}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="list-float-right">
    <ul>
        <div *ngFor="let years of yearData">
            <ng-container *ngIf="years.year == selectedYear">
                <li *ngFor="let months of years.monthData">
                    {{months.month}}
                </li>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>

<div *ngFor=" let years of yearData ">
    <ng-container *ngIf="years.year == selectedYear">
        <div id={{years.year}}>
            {{years.year}}
            <br>
          The color of animals <br>is by no means <br>a matter of chance;
           <br>it depends on many considerations, 
           <br>but in the majority of cases tends to protect the animal 
           from danger by rendering it less conspicuous. 
       <hr>
      </div>
    </ng-container> 
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
selectedYear:any = new Date().getFullYear()
```

**See [Demo Stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2pwsu7)**

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check the simple code without any hack .

your **HTML CODE**

```
<div class="list-float-right">
    <ul >                  
      <li *ngFor="let years of yearData">
        <a  (click)="clickOnYear(years.year)">{{years.year}}</a> 
          </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="list-float-right">
    <ul>                  
      <div *ngFor="let data of yearData">
        <ng-container *ngIf="data.year == selectedYear" >
          <li *ngFor="let month of data.monthData">
            {{month.month}}
          </li>   
        </ng-container>
        <br>
     </div>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div *ngFor="let years of yearData">
    <div *ngIf="years.year == selectedYear">
      {{years.year}}
      <br>
          The color of animals <br>is by no means <br>a matter of chance;
           <br>it depends on many considerations, 
           <br>but in the majority of cases tends to protect the animal 
           from danger by rendering it less conspicuous. 
       <hr>
    </div>
```

**YOUR .ts CODE**

```
//declare global
 yearData = [{
    year:2019,
    monthData: [
      { month : "jan"},
      { month : "july"}
    ]
  },{
    year:2018,
    monthData: [
      { month : "march"},
      { month : "april"}
    ]
  },{
    year:2017,
    monthData: [
      { month : "march"},
      { month : "dec"}
    ]
  },{
    year:2016,
    monthData: [
      { month : "march"},
      { month : "feb"}
    ]
  },{
    year:2015,
    monthData: [
      { month : "jan"},
      { month : "may"}
    ]
  }
];
 selectedYear = 2019;


//function
clickOnYear(val){
    console.log(val)
    this.selectedYear = val;
  }
```

You can check the output in this **[LINK](https://angular-ehojtj.stackblitz.io)**

Answer (score 0):

try below code

**HTML**

```
<div class="list-float-right">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let years of yearData">
            <a href=#{{years.year}} (click)="selectedYear = years.year">{{years.year}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="list-float-right">
    <ul>
        <div *ngFor="let years of yearData">
            <ng-container *ngIf="years.year === selectedYear">
                <li *ngFor="let months of years.monthData">
                    {{months.month}}
                </li>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>

<div *ngFor=" let years of yearData">
    <ng-container *ngIf="years.year === selectedYear">
        <div id={{years.year}}>
            {{years.year}}
            <br>
          The color of animals <br>is by no means <br>a matter of chance;
           <br>it depends on many considerations, 
           <br>but in the majority of cases tends to protect the animal 
           from danger by rendering it less conspicuous. 
       <hr>
      </div>
        </ng-container> 
  </div>
```

**Typescript**

```
selectedYear: any;

ngOnInit() {
  selectedYear = yearData.map(value=> value.year).sort((a, b) => a+b)[0];
}
```